# Unity VR scene to 2D scene

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, 3d, 2d

Does anyone have any idea how to switch unity VR mode scene to normal 2D scene?
i have number of 2D and VR scenes in my application and want a button through which user can enter into VR scene and after then easily return back to normal 2D scenes. I successfully done switching scene between 2D to VR but now my app stuck in VR to 2D switching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look into the documentation on [Hybrid Apps with Google VR](https://developers.google.com/vr/develop/unity/guides/hybrid-apps), it explains how you can go between 2D and VR.

Essentially, you will have to include under the **Player Settings -> XR Settings -> Virtual Reality SDKs** the "None" SDK. You may want to use something like `string vrDeviceName = XRSettings.loadedDeviceName` to store what your VR SDK is when in VR.

You also have to be familiar with using [Coroutines](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html), since when you change the view VR view type, you need to wait one frame.

To switch to 2D, you have to start a coroutine call `XRSettings.LoadDeviceByName("");` and wait one frame, and then adjust the camera (if needed).

To switch back to VR, you start a coroutine to do `XRSettings.LoadDeviceByName(vrDeviceName);` and again wait one frame.